# Flash Command Line Interface

Tags: flash, actionscript, simulation, command-line-interface

I am looking to build a Flash/ActionScript 2 Command Line interface simulator which acts like a Unix/Dos CLI.  Does anyone know how to do this, or have a good resource like a tutorial about it.  I've been scouring the web for a solution, but only seem to be able to find a tutorial about the effect, not actually having it interactive.

A similar effect which is done is JavaScript can be seen here: 
http://thrind.xamai.ca/

Thanks to those who respond.

Comment: have you looked at the Javascript code from your example, it hasn't been minified & is pretty well commented. It may give you some insight...?

Comment: Thank you for the insight, ill start looking over that.

Answer (score 0):

Long time ago I started to work on something like this.

The code is on [github](http://github.com/arthur-debert/flell) .  But, there isn't much documentation and there's some work to be done. Never the less, it's a pretty solid base, if you care to read through the code.

Hope it helps.

Arthur